Where to find the implementation of java.lang.invoke.VarHandle.compareAndSet()?
In java.lang.invoke.VarHandle.java, there is a method compareAndSet which is defined like that:
public final native
@MethodHandle.PolymorphicSignature
@IntrinsicCandidate
boolean compareAndSet(Object... args);

As I understand, the keyword native implies that it is (possibly) implemented via C/C++. If that is so, could you provide the link to the C/C++ source file that implements the compareAndSet?

Why don't you check out the JDK source code and look for it yourself?

@MarkRotteveel Already did yet I didn’t find anything remotely relevant. I have no clue where to find all the JNI stuff, thus asking.

Cloned the JDK in question and run grep "VarHandle_compareAndSet" $(find . -type f -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp"). Needless to say, it did not return any matches.

From a quick look all methods from the MethodHandle and VarHandle classes are specialcased all over the JVM. Take a look at Method::make_method_handle_intrinsic. Somewhere in there the method compareAndSet is mapped to an intrinsic ID (vmIntrinsics::_compareAndSet{Reference,Byte,Short,Int,Long}), and finally LibraryCallKit::try_to_inline constructs graph nodes for each intrinsic.
Finally the different compilers in the JDK map these graph nodes to platform-specific assembly snippets.
Hope that helps you in your journey; feel free to add your own answer (that is hopefully much more in-depth)

Close. Need to dig deeper, yet +1 to you.

This is obviously going to differ between implementations of the JDK, and more importantly between different types of VarHandles but you can find several OpenJDK implementations simply delegating to sun.misc.Unsafe e.g. here and here in the source code.  In general, I recommend tracing things from the factory that produces the VarHandle object itself.
